# Prolog compact?

Tags: prolog, calc, derivative

I have a problem, I need to compact a derivative result like this:

```
0*x*x + 2*(1*x + x*1) =====> example: 0+2*(2*x) =====> 0+2*4*x====>8*x
```

Is it possible? Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Volter

Comment: It is usually called simplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, it just takes some work. You'll need to write out atomic rules such as

```
rule(0*_, 0).
rule(_*0, 0).
rule(1*X, X).
rule(X*1, X).
```

and implement a fixpoint predicate (maybe a [failure-driven loop](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/milca/courses/coal/html/node162.html)) that applies rules until convergence.

Comment: thanks the answer, but how to split this "string" to atomic formulas?

Comment: i need a cycle, to decompress all terms?

Comment: @flatronflow: you'll want to write a [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) for your expressions.